# Rails more then one empty space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, whitespace

I want to retrieve string from database with rails (Rails 2.3.8 andy jruby 1.6.5.1) that looks like "I am     human", but in a browser it always looks like  "I am human". There is no extra spaces in between. How can I keep extra spaces, or what is striping the string.

Operation is pretty simple, just pull a string and show it in view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is stripping the string - it's the semantics of HTML that is screwing you over. All consecutive spaces in HTML are rendered as a single space, unless explicitly prevented by a `<pre>` element, or equivalent CSS rule ([white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/white-space)). You can also keep your spaces if you convert them to another kind of space - a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) does not get collapsed.

Answer (score 1):

browsers interpret usual spaces this way. One can use `&nbsp;` to keep spaces. 
do

```
string_from_db.gsub(' ', '&nbsp;')
```

or use `<pre>` tag.

Comment: You have to mark `&nbsp;` as code or it gets rendered by SO :p

Comment: @Amadan That is exactly what is happening to me, it gets rendered as "&nbsp;". How to render is as code?

Comment: @SonOfOmer , use html_safe method e.g.`string_from_db.gsub(' ', '&nbsp;').html_safe` or raw helper `raw string_from_db.gsub(' ', '&nbsp;')`